# Group by and count of other column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
age   gender   criticality    acknowledged       
 10    Male       High            Yes
 10    Male       High            Yes
 10    Male       High            Yes
 10    Male       Low             Yes
 11    Female     Medium          No
```

I want to groupby age and gender, and then put values of 'criticality', 'acknowledged' as new columns and get the count.

For eg output i desire is:

```
                 criticality          acknowledged
age  gender    High   Medium   Low     Yes    No
 10    Male    3       0       1        4     0
 11    Female  0       1       0        0     1
```

I thought of using `df.groupby(['age','gender'])['criticality','acknowledged'].stack()`

But its not working.

Is there a better way to get results in this format

Answer (score 2):

Since you are counting for the two columns separately, a concat would be an easy solution:

```py
In [13]: pd.concat([df.pivot_table(index=['age', 'gender'], columns=col, aggfunc
    ...: =len) for col in ['criticality', 'acknowledged']], axis=1).fillna(0)
Out[13]: 
            acknowledged             criticality     
criticality         High  Low Medium          No  Yes
age gender                                           
10  Male             3.0  1.0    0.0         0.0  4.0
11  Female           0.0  0.0    1.0         1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `groupby()` after [`assigning`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and finally split the columns with `expand=True` for Multiindex:

```
l=['criticality','acknowledged']
final=df[['age','gender']].assign(**pd.get_dummies(df[l])).groupby(['age','gender']).sum()
final.columns=final.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)
print(final)
```

---

```
                     criticality       acknowledged    
                   High Low Medium           No Yes
age gender                                        
10  Male             3   1      0            0   4
11  Female           0   0      1            1   0
```